# How can I calculate differences between goal occurrences in consecutive soccer games?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate a series of times between goals scored by a team in consecutive soccer games - which each last 90 minutes. Here is an example of the start of the series

```
df <- structure(list(game = c(1, 1, 2, 3), time = c(28, 39, NA, 52)), .Names = c("game", 
                                                                             "time"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

So in this example two goals were scored in game 1, none in game 2 and one in game 3.

The output should be
28,11,203...

I would be happy using dplyr or base R

TIA

Comment: Couldn't understand the `203`

Comment: @akun Sorry hope this clarifies. Each game lasts 90 minutes. So there was a gap between the second goal in the first game to the goal in the third game of ((90-39)+90+52)=203

Comment: @Raphael Tx very much for picking up my slip on 193 and taking the time out to reply. Yep I was looking for something more elegant :). Pretty sure it's out there. I'll have to give it some more thought

Comment: @akun Sorry should have been 193, My 8 year old would never let me live it down

Comment: You should definitely update your (currently incorrect) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution.

```
library("dplyr")

games <- data_frame(
  game = c(1, 1, 2, 3),
  time = c(28, 39, NA, 52)
)

games %>%
  filter(!is.na(time)) %>% 
  mutate(
    game_start = (game - 1) * 90,
    goal_time = game_start + time,
    diff = goal_time - lag(goal_time, default = 0)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Hadley. I was working on a solution involving setting up a separate games data.frame with a cumulative total minutes field  and left_joining but yours is much neater

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution for the problem, but I'm sure there are more efficient and elegant alternative solutions:

```
time.series <- numeric(0)
j <- 1
if(!is.na(df$time[1])) 
{
  time.series[j] <- df$time[1]
  j <- j + 1
} else
  time.series[j] <- 90

for(i in 2:nrow(df))
{
  if(df$game[i-1]==df$game[i])
  {
    time.series[j] <- df$time[i] - df$time[i-1]
    j <- j + 1
  }
  else 
  {
    if(!is.na(df$time[i-1])) 
    {
      if(is.na(df$time[i]))
      {
        time.series[j] <- (90 - df$time[i-1]) + 90
      }
      else 
      {
        time.series[j] <- (90 - df$time[i-1]) + df$time[i]
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if(is.na(df$time[i]))
        time.series[j] <- time.series[j] + 90
      else 
      {
        time.series[j] <- time.series[j] + df$time[i]
        j <- j + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this code on your example creates the vector `time.series` with the expected output:

```
time.series
[1]  28  11 193
```

Just note that in your example, the last entry should be 193, because ((90-39)+90+52) = 193.

Also, if there are no goals in the last game(s), the last entry of `time.series` will be the 90 minutes of the last game(s) plus the the time since the last goal. I'm not sure if that would be what you want, but it should be relatively simple to change in case it is not.